# PDO sql query not executing and not loading html contents further down

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

This PHP code is not printing anyhting and also not able to print the HTML beneath it as well....

The databases and the table are set up and running perfectly. but this query doesnt seem to execute.

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=tipcc;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'root', 'plsdonthack');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt=$db->prepare ("INSERT INTO submissions (NAME,TIME,MEMORY,LANG,LINK)
                    VALUES
                        (:name,:time,:memory,:lang,:link)");

    $stmt->bindParam (':name',$_COOKIE['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam (':time',$details['time'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam (':memory',$details['memory'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam (':lang',$details['langName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam (':link',$details['link'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if ($stmt->execute ())
            {
                echo "hoel";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "loal";
            }
?>
// Some HTML Below.
```

Error Report :

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'LINK' cannot be null' in /var/www/html/TIP-CC/my_php2.php:171 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/TIP-CC/my_php2.php(171): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/TIP-CC/my_php2.php on line 171`

Comment: Where is your $details array?Dont tell me you have the HTML with the array AFTER the php??

Comment: $details = $client->getSubmissionDetails( $user, $pass, $result['link'], true, true, true, true, true ); It is the return value of the API provided by IDEONE

Comment: Do a var_dump of $details before bindParam

Comment: If using `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` didn't report any errors (*or does it?*), then add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: `( $user, $pass, $result['link'], true, true, true, true, true )` - 3 and 5. Seems to be some form of count mismatch along with your query, wouldn't you say?

Comment: As @Fred-ii- said , turn on error reporting , you must have some fatal error as HTML is not displayed. You could surround your code with try catch and print out error message

Comment: SQL may also be *failing silently* due to column lengths or other reason(s) unknown to man.

Comment: I HAVE ADDED THE ERROR REPORT ALSO

Comment: Your error message tells you exactly what you need to know. `$details['link']` is likely null.

Comment: yea...the details['result'] is empty...The plugin in probably failing....due to some other reason..

Comment: You could either check with an if statement before the INSERT operation that the conditions needed are met - or you could catch this error with `try ... catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple:

I had to use the return value of the function. I was using the `IDEONE` API incorrectly.

`$result = $client->createSubmission( $user, $pass, $input_code, $lang, $input_data, $run, $private );`

and use it as `$result['link']`